# Existence of a choice function for finite sets in Jech

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Jech notes in [Chapter 5](https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&id=WTAl997XDb4C&q=axiom+of+choice#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Set Theory, 2003 that, given a family of nonempty sets $S$, in some cases the existence of choice function can be proved in ZF:

> (iii) when every X ∈ S is a finite set of real numbers; let f (X) = the least element of X.

However, in the very next sentence it is stated:

> ... one cannot prove existence of a choice function (in ZF) just from the assumption that the sets in $S$ are finite; **even when every $X \in S$
>   has just two elements (e.g., sets of reals)**, we cannot necessarily prove that $S$ has a choice function.

*(emphasis mine)*

How is this not a contradiction with (iii)?

Comment: I think he means that the elements of $X$ are sets of reals.

Comment: Which book, where in the book? Citations should be as complete as possible.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, noted, added the link to the chapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real numbers are linearly ordered. So given a [non-empty] finite set, it has a well-defined minimum and maximum.

This allows us to define a uniform choice from *all* the [non-empty] finite subsets of the real line: simply pick the minimum of each set.

However, not every set is a set of real numbers. And not every *finite set* is a finite set of real numbers. And indeed it is consistent that there is a countable family of sets of size $2$ without a choice function. As a consequence, it means that if $S$ is a set such that all of these pairs are subsets of $S$, then $S$ cannot be linearly ordered.

The boldface part is mentioning that the elements of the finite sets are themselves *sets* of reals. Not real numbers, and not finite set of real numbers. And so, there is no longer a canonical way of choosing an element from each finite set.

Therefore, it follows, also, that with only $\sf ZF$, not every set can be linearly ordered.